# Importing *.DAT file into SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to import *.DAT file(as flat file source) into sql server using SQL server import and export wizard. It has DC4 as delimiter which is causing error while trying to separate the columns and their respective data and importing them in sql server.

Are there any setting changes to be made during the importing process?

Comment: Do you have to use the wizard? What is your row terminator and what is your field terminator (one of those is DC4, what is the other)?

Comment: Hi HoneyBadger,    I have used the wizard to do the import process.the other field terminator is þ

Comment: on the whole it is xyzþDC4þabcþDC4þefgþDC4þQSTþCRLF

Answer (score 1):

If you don't **have** to use the wizard, you can script it like:

```
BULK INSERT [your_database].[your_schema].[your_table]
    FROM 'your file location.dat' 
    WITH (ROWTERMINATOR='0x04' -- DC4 char
,MAXERRORS=0
,FIELDTERMINATOR='þ'
,TABLOCK
,CodePage='RAW'
)
```

Comment: thanks for the swift reply. I do not have the permission to do bulk insert into the database. Is there any other way so I can import. Each file that I need to import is of 10 MB in size

Comment: You could try if selecting `0x04` in the wizard works as well. I have no experience with the wizard, so I don't know.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: if you pass 0x04 to the wizard, it will throw an exception during the exception. It doesn't  save the package so It's difficult do understand why.

Comment: This solution has several limitations: it requires BULK OPERATIONS permission. The server must have access to the file path. If the file is saved on a network resource, the server account must be a domain account.

Comment: @ildanny...Thanks for clearing that up. I never pretended this was the ultimate solution to the problem, it's just the best one I knew. I like the approach of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The wizard uses SSIS under the hood. Instead of executing it directly, chose CrLF as row delimiter, then chose to save it as file. Open the file and edit it using any text editor. It's a simple xml file.

It's not clear whether 0x04 is the column delimiter or the row delimiter. Assuming it's the row delimiter, 
Replace all instances of

```
Delimiter="_x000D__x000A_"
```

with

```
Delimiter="_x0004_"
```

there're two instances: DTS:HeaderRowDelimiter and DTS:ColumnDelimiter

Save the file and execute it with a double clik or "Open with: Execute package utility". I tested the solution on my PC using an account with limited permissions.

Comment: Thank you ildanny